# Convert a String to CLLocationDistance

Tags: swift, cllocationdistance

I cannot find any examples of how to convert a `String` to `CLLocationDistance`. For example:

```
let distance : String = "2000.0"
let mdf = MKDistanceFormatter()
mdf.units = .Metric
var clDistance = mdf.distanceFromString(distance)
```

I always get `clDistance = -1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to clarify what the `2000` are. Meters, Kilometers etc. Like that:

```
let distance : String = "2000.0m"
let mdf = MKDistanceFormatter()
mdf.units = .Metric
var clDistance = mdf.distanceFromString(distance)
```

The `distanceFromString` returns the distance as meters.

Comment: Doesn't this round is significantly?